# Rails is defaulting to capitalizing only first letter of first word, rather than what I type into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Just curious if there was a rule about this.... and how to get around it. Basically when I call a variable with a string that is `Daypack (<40L)` or `Tent (1-Person)" for example, whatever the content, the output in the view only capitalizes the first letter of the first word. And what I want is for whatever I type in caps to be capitalized in the view.

With the following hash in the controller:

```
@itemlist = {
  "Camping" => ["Tent (1-person)", "Tent (2-person)", "Tent (3-person)", "Tent (4-person)", "Tent (6-person)", "Tent (8-person)", "Sleeping bag", "Sleeping pad", "Camp pillow", "Daypack (<40L)", "Daypack cover"]
  }
```

In the view I'm teasing part the category (camping) and the items within that category (the array associated with Camping) are assigned to label_tags. That's where the capitalization is messing up.

```
<% @itemlist.each do |category, list| %>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group" style="font-size:80%">
      <h5> <%="#{category}"%> </h5>
        <% list.each do |thing| %>
            <%= label_tag "#{thing}" %>
          </br>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your variables are all already strings. Get rid of every instance of `"#{}"` in your code, they're all doing nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`label_tag` takes one, two or three arguments. If you give it one, it's the *name* of the label, and it guesses the tag's text. If you want to control the tag's text, give it two arguments:

```
<%= label_tag thing, thing %>
```

From [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label):

```
label_tag 'name'
# => <label for="name">Name</label>

label_tag 'name', 'Your name'
# => <label for="name">Your name</label>

label_tag 'name', nil, class: 'small_label'
# => <label for="name" class="small_label">Name</label>
```